# how to make a game tutorial of flash game?

Tags: actionscript-3, game-theory

how to make a game tutorial as farmville game tutorial to teach the user to play the game. i have recently involve in make that kind of game tutorial for its user by actionscript 3, can anyone give me a guide to do it? any help is appreciated~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to do this is similar to the "achievements system" many games employ, which utilises the a system similar to the Observer design pattern.
You'd set up a globally-accesible receiver object, with a function to receive a data packet of some sort.

Then, every function that should effect the tutorial info being shown would message this receiver object, and tell it of it's performed action.

So, say for instance, that you have a message box up to tell the player to "Chop down 10 trees".
You could then have a Receiver object with a function like `TutorialMessage(var Action:String, var Parameter:object):void`

When they perform the "Chop down tree" action, then end of the chopDownTree() function would contain a call to the receiver object's messaging function `Receiver.TutorialMessage("TreeChoppedDown", 1)` (ie, Chopped down 1 tree).

That receiver would then, essentially, run a massive switch case to determine the nature of the action, and interpret would to do based on your logic. In this case, it would add the value of Parameter to some counter variable, and when it reached 10, would display the next tutorial message.

Comment: Thanks, Jordaan Mylonas. How about the forcing action? Is there a way to only allow a button to be click? I want it to force the user to follow the sequence for finish the the tutorial as expected. Do anyone has the clue?

Comment: Not too disimilar. Establish a globally accessible object that handles action permissions. Under general play circumstances, it allows any action within the game's rules. In tutorial, it is much more strict. Give it a function `CanPerform(Action:String):bool`, and any time a game-state-affect action is to occur, wrap it in a permission checking if block. ie, `if(Ruleset.CanPerform("KillSomeDude")){KillADude();}`